# How do I get a password hint from an Access Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I'm currently making a C# winforms POS application, using an Microsft Access database (since its the only type of database I know how to use)

I need to get a password hint field, only knowing the username field in the database. Basically, if the user forgets their password, they can enter their username, and get their hint.

I know I need to use some kind of SQL query, but I don't know exactly how to form it. I'm able to login the user with their password. I have tried this SQL query; `SELECT Username, [Hint] FROM Users WHERE [Username] = ? AND [Hint] = ?`

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
EB.

Comment: why would you filter on `AND [Hint] = ?`?!? What you want is the row of user x nothing more so your filter should only be `WHERE [Username] = ?`

Comment: Aside: Are you sure that you need the `Username` returned from a query that only returns rows for a single value of `Username`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need only this:

```sql
SELECT [Hint] FROM Users WHERE [Username] = ?
```

Comment: When I try this, the data adapter gives me an error saying the two other fields (username and password) are empty. Here is the actual error: ```System.Data.ConstraintException: 'Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.'```

Comment: Also, when I view the data table using the debugger, it shows that it gets the actual hint, but returns null for the username and password field. Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/8CU7O4J.png

Comment: EDIT: I got it to work using this query: ```SELECT [Hint] FROM Users WHERE [Username] = ?```. Then getting the value of the hint using this code: ```string hint = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(2);```